# How to perform a division between two tables in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables in python

```
table 1  

1   24

2   25

3   26

table 2

0   4

1   5

2   2
```

when I type `table1/tabl2`

It gives me all NaN

What I want to achieve here is getting a new table as below to show the division results

```
table3

1 6

2 5

3 13
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Please format your question using markdown, so people can read the question with more ease: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: [JFYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Please provide code (a minimal example). Nobody knows what you mean with "table".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did't mention in which format your data is. But I have example of Pandas DataFrame if you use DataFrame you will get required results.

```
import pandas as pd

t1 = pd.DataFrame([24,25,26] , columns=['values'])
t2 = pd.DataFrame([4,5,2] , columns=['values'])

print(t1/t2)
```

**Output**

```
   values
0     6.0
1     5.0
2    13.0
```

If you want integer output please use `t1//t2`

Comment: Yes, it's two dataframe tables. Do I have to manually type out the [24,25,26] and [4,5,2]? Because my actual data has like 100+ rows in it. Say if [24,25,26] column header is sales, and [4,5,2] column header is quantity, is there a way to just put "sales/quantity"? Thanks

Comment: Yes there are several ways. Try `dataframe["sales"] / dataframe["quantity"]`

Comment: Thanks, it works. But just want to confirm that, in my original dataframe, table 1 has index 1-3 while table 2 has index 0-2, I have to reindex make both them 1-3 to have correct result right? Because when using dataframe["sales"] / dataframe["quantity"], python is looking for data point with same index to do the math operation, if I have 0-2 and 1-3, index 0 and index 3 only exist in one table and thus would return NaN?

Comment: Yes. so you should better re-index your dataframes.

Comment: And if my solution helped you so please marked it as the best answer by clicking on the green check besides my answer.